# May I short this mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I use this query in my script :

```
SELECT *
FROM `login_messages`
WHERE  `user_id` = :user_id
      AND `to` = :to
      AND (`date` BETWEEN :date AND NOW())
   OR     `user_id` = :to
      AND `to` = :user_id
      AND (`date` BETWEEN :date AND NOW())
ORDER BY `login_messages`.`date` ASC
```

Is there anyway to use this part

```
(
    AND (`date` BETWEEN :date AND NOW())
)
```

just once in query ? and this is not important in query loading speed ?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN` clause

**Try This**

```
SELECT *
FROM login_messages
WHERE ((user_id ='userid1' AND TO ='to1')
    OR (user_id ='to1' AND TO ='userid1'))
  AND (`date` BETWEEN :date AND NOW())
ORDER BY `login_messages`.`date` ASC
```

Comment: The result won't be the same because this allows `user_id` and `to` to have the same value unlike the original query.